# PostgreSQL - Grant privileges as superuser

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a question about the rights in PG (version 10).

I did 2 tests.

The scenario is the following:

- create a db with the superuser
- create a schema owned by a user
- create a read only role
- grant privileges to the role
- grant role to the read only user
- create a table in the specific schema with the user that owns it

When I grant the privileges as a superuser, the "testuser" can't read the table: **test KO**.

When I grant the privileges as the owner of the schema, "testuser" can read the table: **test OK**

Why the superuser can't grant the privileges on a schema owned by another user ?

```
TEST KO

pg_ctl stop -D .
rm -rf *
pg_ctl init -D .
pg_ctl start -D .
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create database testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create user testuser"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create role role_read_testdb"

psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "create schema authorization testuser"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA testuser GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA testuser GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES to role_read_testdb"

psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create user user_read"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "grant role_read_testdb to user_read"

psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "create table t1(col1 int)"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U user_read -c "select count(1) from testuser.t1"
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t1

TEST OK

pg_ctl stop -D .
rm -rf *
pg_ctl init -D .
pg_ctl start -D .
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create database testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create user testuser"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create role role_read_testdb"

psql -p 5432 -d testdb -c "create schema authorization testuser"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA testuser TO role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA testuser GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to role_read_testdb"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA testuser GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES to role_read_testdb"

psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "create user user_read"
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c "grant role_read_testdb to user_read"

psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -c "create table t1(col1 int)"
psql -p 5432 -d testdb -U user_read -c "select count(1) from testuser.t1"
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you please remove the shell command part of the commands?  It would make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` without a `FOR ROLE` clause alters the default privileges for objects created by only the current role (the role executing the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`).  So in the first case, you altered the superuser's default privileges, which has no effect on `testuser`'s default privileges.